# How can I invoke a PHP file, then the other PHP page be refresh?

Tags: php, html

I have two php files, one is `source.php` and the other is `target.php`.

in the `target.php` there have ready the refresh method:

```
<?php

function invoke(){
    echo "<script>refresh_page();</script>";
}

if(isset($_POST['source']) && $_POST['source'] == 'source'){  
    invoke();

}

?>

<div>
    <h1>this is target</h1>

    <button onclick="refresh_page()">refresh</button>
</div>

<script>
    function refresh_page(){
        history.go(0);
    }
</script>
```

in the `source.php`:

I use the `curl` for request the `target.php`:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "target.php");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$data = array(
    'source'=>'source'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

My requirement is, when I execute the `source.php` the `target.php`(have opened in my browser) should refresh.

I tested my code, it do not refresh. who can tell me how to do with this?

---

**EDIT01**

My requirement is I have two PHP page, `target.php` and `source.php`.

when I opened them, I want to use `source.php` to refresh the `target.php`, just this.

[image]

Comment: _“I tested my code, it do not refresh”_ - well of course it doesn’t … You requested `target.php` on the server side via cURL, this has absolutely no connection whatsoever to what you have currently opened in your browser. _“who can tell me how to do with this?”_ - that depends on what you actually want to achieve by this, which is rather unclear as of now. _Why_ are you making a server-side request using cURL, and _why_ is that supposed to refresh anything you have currently shown in your browser? What is the actual condition or event upon which you need to refresh this?

Comment: @misorude See my edit01, brother. this is my requirement, I just want to in one page to refresh the other page.

Comment: There currently is no connection between those two documents, that would make this possible. This would need to happen on the client side, so any attempts using cURL on the server side make no sense to begin with. You would need some JS code inside source.php, and that code would need to “know” about the window/tab the other script is opened in … which you basically can only get, if you opened target.php _from_ source.php using JavaScript or a link with a target attribute pointing to a frame in the first place.

Comment: postMessage would be an approach to let the two documents communicate with each other. Then target.php could reload _itself_, when it gets the message from source.php instructing it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

what about using the Location header to redirect instead of javascript?

`<?php header("Location: {$url}"); ?>`

To call another script you could use include (http://php.net/manual/de/function.include.php) or require (http://php.net/manual/de/function.require.php)

`<?php include('target.php'); ?>`